# How to \flushleft and \flushright in the same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to write:

```
Proof. Skipped. \flushright$\Box$
```

in the same line and this outputs two  lines.

Comment: Does `Proof. Skiped. \hfill $\Box$` does what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! This is exacly what I wanted to do!!

Comment: Remember that `\usepackage{amsthm}` provides `\begin{proof}Skiped.\end{proof}`.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Proof. Skiped. \hfill $\square$

\end{document}
```

[image]